# SwiftUI List freezes on @ObservedObject update

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui, observedobject

I have the List which automatically fetches more data near the end:

```
struct AdCardListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: AdListViewModel = AdListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List { ForEach(self.model.adArray.enumerated().map({ $0 }), id: \.element.id) { index, ad in
                AdCardView(ad: ad)
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let count = self.model.adArray.count
                            if index >= count - 5 { //5 Views to the end, start loading more.
                                self.model.fetch(count: count)
                            }
                        }
                }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Model looking like:

```
final class AdListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var adArray = [Ad]()
    ...
 func fetch(count: Int = 0) {
    ...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.adArray.append(contentsOf: newAds) //<-- problem here
    }
    ...
}
```

My problem: every @Published/@ObservedObject modification I have a little freeze when scroll list. Also, I found that List recalculates the body of all visible views + a few views above and below.

But I can't determine what leads to hangs of scrolling and fix it (maybe freeze is a transfer to a distance equal to (scrolling speed * rendering time)?

Why SwiftUI recalculate bodies on the existing views? They have not changed!

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recreation of the body should not be an issue.I doubt that the performance issue is related with the update animations of the List.

Did you try adding `.id(UUID())` modifier to your List so that animations are discarded and the list is recreated after updates.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but nothing changed. But I tried only on top-level view inside the row. Do I need to set id on all views inside a top-level view?

Comment: this answer fixed it for me: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui

Comment: Awesome! Save my years!